# Refreshing of ads in android

Tags: android, admob, ads

In my android app I'm trying to add ads. I have a doubt about refreshing of ad.

Is it need to refresh the ad manually to get new ads?
What will be the benefit if I manually refresh the ads?

I tried calling  `adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());` function in an interval but I'm getting same ads each time.

Comment: You may not see it change to a different ad every time. Which ad is shown depends on many many things. There are times that it just doesn't have anything new lined up to show, in which case it might just stick with whichever one it gave you last time. Have you tested this over a long period? i.e. a few days?

Comment: Should i need to refresh the adView manually ?

Comment: I'm testing it for the last 2 days

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no guarantee that you'll get a new ad but you shouldn't really be refreshing the ad from within the app. Instead within the admob interface there is an option for automatic ad refreshing.

If you login to your admob account go to sites & apps > select Manage Settings under your app name, (hover the mouse around the app name). Then click on the app settings tab. You should then see an automatic refresh option which is set to either use in client code, which I believe is what your doing, or none, or automatic refresh and you can provide an interval of how often it will refresh save you having to do it from code.

Comment: Sir kindly let me know if automatic refreshing effects the speed or not .